# How did Pushing Daisies get its name?

Tags: title-explanation, pushing-daisies

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while. This show is about a person who can bring back people from the dead. How would it get the name Pushing Daisies? Thanks!

Comment: It's common knowledge. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pushing_up_daisies

Comment: It's common knowledge for native English speakers.  It's an idiom that people who learned English as a second language aren't going to know.

Comment: I'm going to argue that while to some, it might seem common, it's actually rather hard to search for it, leading me to believe it isn't common knowledge. Try searching for the answer in google, and see what you come up with.

Comment: @Keen: I speak English as a primary language, and had never heard the idiom...

Comment: @Keen But looking it up in a dictionary (like my link) gives a correct answer.

Comment: My initial urge was to VTC, but I think the answer to this only seems obvious in hindsight, to those who are already familiar with the idiom.

Comment: [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/push+daisies) (2nd Google hit for "push daisies" for me) does give the meaning: “Push up daisies. Informal. To be dead and buried.”

Comment: Despite being "common knowledge", there are some good bits of information here, especially Meyer's answer.

Comment: This kind of question is better asked on English.SE.

Comment: @Robert the question isn't about the etymology of the phrase (which would belong on English.SE) but about why a SF/F show has the name it has.  (My answer includes details of etymology, but that's just background for the central answer to the SF/F question).

Comment: @user1027 Khey! Eengleesh as second langvedge heer, and qvite fameeliar viz ze idiom!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Pushing daisies" is an euphemism for being dead. Urban dictionary [puts it this way](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pushing%20daisies):

> Dead. Your body is dead in the ground, and being used as fertilizer by
>   plants. Hence you are "pushing" plants up from the ground.

Answer (score 28):

The phrase "pushing up daisies" is often linked to [Keats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Keats), who is attributed as saying:

> I shall soon be laid in the quiet grave -- thank God for the quiet grave -- O! I can feel the cold earth upon me -- the daisies growing over me -- O for this quiet -- it will be my first.

(letter from Joseph Severn to John Taylor, Mar. 6, 1821).

(Image originally from [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/patrickdown/2461429480/))
[image: TNCWC 24 - Opposites by Patrick_Down, on Flickr]

However, the link between daisies and death (particularly innocent death) is much older than that.  The Celtic poet Ossian wrote how unborn children would return to the ground as flowers:

> a woman named Malvina, who was mourning the death of her baby, was consoled by the Maidens of King Morven. Malvina was told that her child had turned into a flower with a golden disk surrounded by silvery petals. It supposedly looked like an infant playing in a field.

(text from [JSTOR Plant Science](https://web.archive.org/web/20131006105202/http://jstorplants.org/2010/07/09/pushing-up-daisies-celtic-lore-hamlet-and-a-literary-strangehold/), but the legend connecting daises and the spirits of dead children is common).

Daisies are thus often a choice of flower to lay on a gravesite, and partly because of this, and partly because they [grow easily with no maintenance](http://web.archive.org/web/20140109033430/http://www.ask.com/explore/growing-most-beautiful-daisies), and like many flowers flourish in a nutrient rich soil (although bodies are typically well sealed in coffins now, this was not always the case), they are very commonly found in graveyards.

The exact origin of the phrase "push up daisies" is disputed (e.g. [this site](https://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=buried) claims that it dates from c1860), but it's a fairly simple step from daisies growing above the bodies of the dead to the idiom.

It is certainly at least as old as World World I, when it was used in *A Terre*, a poem by Wilfred Owen about the physical loss suffered by a soldier entrapped within his deteriorating body (this is only part of the poem):

> O Life, Life, let me breathe, - a dug-out rat!
>
> Not worse than ours the existences rats lead -
>
> Nosing along at night down some safe vat,
>
> They find a shell-proof home before they rot.
>
> Dead men may envy living mites in cheese,
>
> Or good germs even. Microbes have their joys,
>
> And subdivide, and never come to death,
>
> Certainly flowers have the easiest time on earth.
>
> "I shall be one with nature, herb, and stone."
>
> Shelley would tell me. Shelley would be stunned;
>
> The dullest Tommy hugs that fancy now.
>
> "Pushing up daisies," is their creed, you know.
>
> To grain, then, go my fat, to buds my sap,
>
> For all the usefulness there is in soap.
>
> D'you think the Boche will ever stew man-soup?
>
> Some day, no doubt, if...

As a name for a show where people *come back* from the dead, it's perhaps particularly apt, since "pushing up daisies" brings to mind (even if this is not the general use of the phrase) images of people rising from the grave, dislodging the daisies around it.

Note that many other [expressions for death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expressions_related_to_death) have already been used, like [taking a dirt nap](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1053834/), [the last roundup](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151306/) (sounds a bit too Western anyway), and most famously, [six feet under](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0248654/), so if that's what the creators were looking for, the list narrows quickly.

Comment: And from Grim Fandango! `We may have days, we may have hours; but sooner or later we all push up flowers.`

Comment: The Keats quote mentions daises, but it doesn't suggest the idea of pushing them (up or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

"Pushing up the daisies" is a pretty well known phrase in the UK. I thought it would be better known elsewhere due to the Monty Python Dead Parrot sketch "If you hadn't nailed 'im to the perch 'e'd be pushing up the daisies!".

I believe that Monty Python, and this most famous sketch in particular, is often considered to be known worldwide.

Answer (score -1):

It's approximately the same expression as the French "fumer les pissenlits par la racine", which literally means "to smoke the daisies from their roots". When you come to think of it, both expressions are very visual and mean the same thing: to be dead.

Comment: You may want to read the full comments on the question.  I was responding to OghmaOsiris and PaperJam.